# How to extract two arrays from a Scala dense vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dense vector.

```
scala> model.coefficients 
res1: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector = (891,[11,20,25,27,28,50],[0.35686135501086036,8.194306936725383E-6,7.62720047518819E-6,9.354557510460644E-4,5.633054601656321E-4,2.5641516558812987E-5])
```

Can someone suggest a way to create two Arrays out of this vector?

Array 1: Array of Indices

```
res2: Array[Int] = Array(11,20,25,27,28,50)
```

Array 2: Array of Values

```
res3: Array[Double] = Array(0.35686135501086036,8.194306936725383E-6,7.62720047518819E-6,9.354557510460644E-4,5.633054601656321E-4,2.5641516558812987E-5)
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated:

(My final goal is to take the model coefficients and select the column names using the index array. ex: Array index 11 could be sales of product A, Array index 20 could be customer Age so on and so forth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you have is a SparseVector.  You can use methods [indices](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector@indices:Array[Int]) and [values](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector@values:Array[Double]) as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector

val vector = new SparseVector(891, Array(11, 20, 25, 27, 28, 50), Array(
  0.35686135501086036, 8.194306936725383E-6, 7.62720047518819E-6,
  9.354557510460644E-4, 5.633054601656321E-4, 2.5641516558812987E-5)
)

vector.indices
// res1: Array[Int] = Array(11, 20, 25, 27, 28, 50)

vector.values
// res2: Array[Double] = Array(0.35686135501086036, 8.194306936725383E-6, 7.62720047518819E-6,
//   9.354557510460644E-4, 5.633054601656321E-4, 2.5641516558812987E-5)
```

Comment: model.coefficients is org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector. How can I convert that to  org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector?

Comment: "model" was created by fitting training data using LogisticRegression.

Comment: You can use method [toSparse](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector@toSparse:org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector) to convert `model.coefficients` to `SparseVector`.